# $|a_n-\alpha|<2\epsilon$ valid as a definition of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My question is concerning the proof below taken from Ivan Wilde’s notes on real analysis which are freely available on the web.

**Is coming within $\large k\epsilon$ [$k\in\mathbb Z$] of a point as effective a proof of convergence as coming within $\large \epsilon$ of it?**

**For** k$\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small.
**Against** - (and specifically regarding the question below) - since the reasoning always comes out at 2$\epsilon$ it cannot ever meet the definition of convergence

- but then you could just substitute and redefine the variable at the last step.
- is there a meaningful analogy between this and one of the better known proofs of the irrationality of $\surd 2$ whereby the numerator of $\frac{p}{q}$ is always even, and it is that which provides the contradiction.

---

THEOREM 
Suppose that $(a_n) [n ∈ N]$ is a sequence such that $a_n$ → α and also $a_n$ → β as n → ∞.
Then α = β, that is, a convergent sequence has a unique limit.

PROOF
Let ε > 0 be given.

Since we know that $a_n$ → α, then we are assured that eventually $(a_n )$ is within ε of α. Thus, $\exists\;N_1 ∈ N:  n > N_1\implies |a_n - α|<ε$

Similarly, we know that $a_n$ → β as n → ∞ and so eventually $(a_n)$ is within ε of β. Thus, $\exists\; N_2 ∈ N:  n > N_2\implies |a_n - α|<ε$

So far so good. What next? To get both of these happening simultaneously, we let $N = max { N_1 , N_2 }$.  Then n > N means that both $n > N_1$ and also $n > N_2$ . Hence we can say that if n > N then both
$| a_n − α | < ε$

and

$| a_n − β | < ε$.

Now what? We expand out these sets of inequalities. n > N (for example n = N + 1 would do). Then

Pick and ﬁx any

$α − ε <a_n < α + ε$

$β − ε < a_n < β + ε$

The left hand side of the ﬁrst pair together with the right hand side of the second pair of inequalities gives $α − ε < a_n < β + ε$ and so

$α − ε < β + ε$.

Similarly, the left hand side of the second pair together with the right hand side of the ﬁrst pair of inequalities gives β − ε < a n < α + ε and so

$β − ε < α + ε$.

Combining these we see that

$−2ε < α − β < 2ε$

which is to say that $\large| α − β | < 2ε$.

This happens for any given ε > 0 and so the non-negative number $| α − β |$ must actually be zero. But this means that α = β and the proof is complete.

Comment: In this example you can think of it this way...The distance $|\alpha - \beta|$, which is a fixed real number, was shown to be smaller than any number of the form $2\varepsilon$, which is to say that $\frac{1}{2}|\alpha-\beta|$ is smaller than every positive real number $\varepsilon$. The only non-negative number that is smaller than every positive number is $0$, whence $\frac{1}{2}|\alpha - \beta| = 0$ and of course $\alpha = \beta$.

Comment: @joeb isn’t the concept of ‘smaller than every positive real number’ rather dodgy?  It seems to imply that there is a smallest number which there is not.

Comment: Another way to finish the proof is to assume that $|\alpha-\beta|>0$ and let $\varepsilon=|\alpha-\beta|$ (which is ok, since you showed the result for all $\varepsilon>0$.) Then you get $|\alpha-\beta|<2\varepsilon=2|\alpha-\beta|$, a contradiction.

Comment: "Smaller than every real number" is dodgy. "Smaller than every $positive$ real number" isn't dodgy at all. The number $0$ is smaller than every positive real number; so are the numbers $-1$ and $-27$.

Comment: Incidentally, you do not even need “for all $\epsilon>0$. It is enough to have $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for almost all $n$ only for the specific value $\frac12|a-b|$ (if $a\ne b$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that method is perfectly fine.   What you want to show is it works for any $\epsilon>0$.    Showing it works for any $k\epsilon$ where $k>0$  is exactly the same,  just by rescaling the $\epsilon$ in question.   You can easily prove that is an if and only if.

If one wants to make the proof "cleaner" you can go back in the steps to find where you need to rescale things to end up with $\epsilon$ and not $2\epsilon$,  but it is usually more work than it is worth

Comment: Brilliant thanks

Comment: No problem.  If your question is answered, you should mark one of the answers as accepted with the check mark.  This shows the question is completed along with awarding a bit of rep

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice question because this sort of argument must be confusing to many beginning calculus students. Thus, it's not a bad idea to check formally that this works. In fact, let $f\colon (0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ be any surjection. Then I claim that the following is equivalent:

1. $(\forall \varepsilon > 0 )(\exists N\in\mathbb N)\ n \geq N \implies |a_n-\alpha| < \varepsilon,$
2. $(\forall \varepsilon > 0 )(\exists N\in\mathbb N)\ n \geq N \implies |a_n-\alpha| < f(\varepsilon).$

*Proof.* (1. implies 2.)
Assume that 1. is true and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, $f(\varepsilon) > 0$ so if we apply 1. to $f(\varepsilon)$ instead of $\varepsilon$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N \implies |a_n-\alpha|<f(\varepsilon)$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary positive real, we have proven 2.

(2. implies 1.)
Assume that 2. is true and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $\varepsilon'>0$ such that $f(\varepsilon')=\varepsilon$ (by surjectivness of $f$) so if we apply 2. to $\varepsilon'$ instead of $\varepsilon$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N \implies |a_n-\alpha|<f(\varepsilon') = \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary positive real, we have proven 1. $\square$

In their answer, Alan writes the following:

> If one wants to make the proof "cleaner" you can go back in the steps to find where you need to rescale things to end up with ϵ and not 2ϵ

This is precisely looking for $\varepsilon' > 0$ such that $f(\varepsilon') = \varepsilon$ in the above proof.

Perhaps surprisingly, $f$ doesn't even have to be surjective onto $(0,+\infty)$. It is enough that the infimum of the range of $f$ is $0$. The proof is almost the same, the only change is that you would want $\varepsilon'>0$ such that $0<f(\varepsilon') < \varepsilon$, which is guaranteed to exist by $0$ being the infimum of $f(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: If the goal is 'don't confuse beginning calculus students', then I might steer away from an explanation that talks about arbitrary surjective functions; this answer is basically accurate, but I feel like much of the terminology in it is much scarier and more confusing to beginning students than the original question.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki, I didn't have intention to write something I would actually teach or advocate to teach to beginning calculus students, I just wanted to write a formal proof because I've never seen one written somewhere (though I'm sure there must be). By the time I read the question, Alan already wrote their answer which is an intuitive explanation, so I added this because I thought it might be interesting to someone, since it sure was interesting to me years ago when I was thinking about this. To me, personally, it was unexpected that $f$ didn't have to be monotone or bijective.

Comment: I certainly appreciated the formal version,  I always like it when additional answers extend existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally correct actually you can fix $ε>0$;

then when applying the definition of convergence in coming steps set $ε'=ε/2>0$
then you will have at the end $ε/2+ε/2=ε$

actually  you can prove easily that for a given function of epsilon $f(ε)$ such that if epsilon goes to 0 , then $f(ε)$ goes to 0 .
if you have $(∃N∈N) n≥N⟹|a_n−α|<f(ε).$

then $(∀ε>0)(∃N'∈N) n≥N'⟹|a_n−α|<ε.$